# How to Modify the Author name in Blog Categories (categories.aspx)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have copied blog.xsl and created Blogwrittenby.xsl to override the author name and display default author name. It works well for all other places except when we see categories.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this, using editing the viewfield option and overwriting blog.xsl.

Please feel free to reach out to me in case more details needed on this.